# SQL Query Condition With Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables namely the class_record, class_violation, violation.

The table class_record has these columns and data:

```
Class Violation CR No.            |        Class ID
000-000                           |        A30-000
000-001                           |        A30-000
```

The table class_violation has these columns and data:

```
Class Violation CR No.            |        Violation ID
000-000                           |        2
000-000                           |        1
000-001                           |        2
000-001                           |        4
000-001                           |        3
```

The table violation has these columns and data:

```
Violation ID                      |        First Amount  |        Second Amount
1                                 |        1000          |        2000
2                                 |        200           |        400
3                                 |        500           |        1000
4                                 |        500           |        1000
```

The table `class_record` contains the information of the class record.

The table `class_violation` is the table that contains what are the violations that is committed. And lastly, the table `violation` contains the information about the violations.

If the violation is committed twice, the second amount will be triggered instead of the first amount. As you can see on table `class_violation`, on `Violation ID` column, number 2 violation id is committed twice. The second amount of the must be the charged amount instead of the first amount. So the total charged amount will be the first amount plus the second amount if committed twice. My question is that how do I get the get the second amount instead of the first amount and get its total amount of the violations committed? So far here is my SQL query but is terribly wrong:

```
SELECT SUM(`First Amount`) 
FROM violation 
WHERE `Violation ID` 
        IN (SELECT `Violation ID` FROM class_violation 
            WHERE `Class Violation No.` 
                     IN (SELECT `Class Violation CR No.` 
                     FROM class_record WHERE `Class ID` = 'A30-000'))
```

Please help me. Sorry for my english. The result of the query must be:

```
SUM
2600
```

Here is my sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2712a

Comment: Have one doubt in your problem statement. The example that you quoted is for Violation ID = 2. But this Violation ID has occured in different Class Violation CR No. Is that still to be counted as twice>? Also, can you create a SQL Fiddle for the same?

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that? I'm just new in SQL queries.

Comment: if you have the CREATE and INSERT statements for these tables, then just go to www.sqlfiddle.com and then Build the schema and share the link.

Comment: Sorry for my english. It will be counted twice but the first amount and second amount added together must be the total charged amount. Ok I'll try thanks alot.

Comment: Hello sorry for the wait here is the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2712a

Comment: Dont worry about the link now. I have already created one and written the query for you. You might have to change some variable names to make it work in your scenario.

Comment: Some observations... 1. This naming policy WILL DRIVE YOU MAD. 2. Consider normalizing `violation`. 3. All tables in RDBMS should have PRIMARY KEYs (otherwise they're not really tables!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this query:

`SELECT class_record.ClassID,SUM(A.VioAmount),GROUP_CONCAT(A.VioAmount)
FROM class_record
INNER JOIN (SELECT class_record.ClassID, class_record.CR_No, IF(COUNT(violation.ViolationID)=1, SUM(FAmount),(FAmount+SAmount)) AS VioAmount
FROM violation 
INNER JOIN class_violation ON violation.ViolationID = class_violation.ViolationID
INNER JOIN class_record ON class_violation.CR_No = class_record.CR_No
WHERE ClassID = 'A30-000'
GROUP BY violation.ViolationID, class_record.ClassID) A ON A.ClassID = class_record.ClassID
AND A.CR_No = class_record.CR_No
GROUP BY class_record.ClassID`

You can check the SQLFiddle too at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d855b/35

Now I am taking the values in a separate Select and then JOINing it with another to obtain the SUM. Hope this solves your problem. All the Best.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is unclear. What I want is the total amount of violations only committed. The total amount charged will be 2600. All added. Because there is only one Class ID that has the violations but on different CR No. The violations will be 200 + 1000 + 400 (Because the second amount will be charged [second offense of violation]) + 500 + 500

Comment: Editing the answer. Pl check that query.

Comment: Hello if I would ask again, if there is a third offense amount, what would be the SQL query?

Comment: That's what I've been doing for hours now and still could not get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need return column "Second amount" if count(Violation ID)=2 and "First amount" if count(Violation ID)=1?

If I understand your question, look for "CASE" operator.